# HttpContext.Current.Session is NULL inside async Task [.NET 4]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, task, httpcontext

```
HttpContext CustomContext = HttpContext.Current;

Task task = new Task(() =>
{
    HttpContext.Current = CustomContext;
    // HttpContext.Current.Session shows null

    // logic goes here
});

task.Start();
```

I read some question in this site & found that

> As HttpContext is bound to thread, that's why it is null in the task.

So that, I save the context in other variable then try to use it. It works fine in case of **HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies**, but **HttpContext.Current.Session** gives me null.

Any explanation or help would be appriciated.